# "glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 3" using Mapzen vector tiles

Tags: mapzen

Suddenly I run into lots of these warnings in the console when using mapzen vector tiles with mapbox-gl:

[.Offscreen-For-WebGL-0x2c91ee109c00]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 3

Before it was working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noticing it happened during zooming from level 15 and higher; and also that I had no warnings when using a simplified stylesheet I found it to be that the stylesheet requirements have altered. In my case I had a filtervalue in one of my stylesheetlayers of `yes` which in new version should be `true`. For more details how to update your stylesheet you could use [this](https://gist.github.com/nvkelso/a7cfec649bb0de49f4ac71596a148a32).